# Syncing Address book to Google Apps doesn't sync groups

Tags: contacts

When I sync my address book on my mac to Google Apps (gmail) it doesn't sync groups. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a supported feature of the address book/google sync.

This support [article](http://www.google.com/support/contactsync/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=92997#anchor_link_4) from Google (point 4) states that

> "Currently, groups are not synced to
>   Gmail. We're hoping to add this
>   functionality in the future."